# Build and run a windows .NET Core app on Debian (Exec format error)

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, debian

I have this ASP .Net Core app which is written on a windows machine using latest Visual studio. Now I need to build and host this app on a Linux machine (Debian latest version).

Project `.csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="3.5.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Installed `dotnet core 3.1` on my Linux using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian).

The output after running `dotnet build` is:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Determining projects to restore...   Restored
> /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj
> (in 1.37 sec).
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error MSB3883: Unexpected exception:
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): Exec format error
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String
> filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean
> redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean
> setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32&
> stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal,
> Boolean throwOnNoExec)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String
> pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool(String
> pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error MSB3883: Unexpected exception:
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): Exec format error
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String
> filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean
> redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean
> setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32&
> stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal,
> Boolean throwOnNoExec)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo
> startInfo)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String
> pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.compilers/3.5.0/tools/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(59,5):
> error : at
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool(String
> pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
> [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]
> 0 Warning(s)
> 7 Error(s)

What is the problem?

Also `dotnet --info` output:

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   3.1.301
> Commit:    7feb845744
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     debian  OS Version:  10  OS
> Platform: Linux  RID:         debian.10-x64  Base Path:
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.301/
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 3.1.5   Commit:  65cd789777
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
> 3.1.301 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5
> [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5
> [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

`lscpu` output:

> Architecture:        x86_64 CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit Byte
> Order:          Little Endian Address sizes:       43 bits physical,
> 48 bits virtual CPU(s):              4 On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
> Thread(s) per core:  1 Core(s) per socket:  1 Socket(s):           4
> NUMA node(s):        1 Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel CPU family:
> 6 Model:               79 Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
> E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz Stepping:            1 CPU MHz:
> 2197.455 BogoMIPS:            4394.91 Hypervisor vendor:   VMware Virtualization type: full L1d cache:           32K L1i cache:
> 32K L2 cache:            256K L3 cache:            30720K NUMA node0
> CPU(s):   0-3 Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8
> apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss
> syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology
> tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid
> sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx
> f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault
> invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle
> avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear
> flush_l1d arch_capabilities

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux

Comment: @jdweng I used a similar link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian. I said it in my post.

Comment: Do you plan on building on linux or building on windows and then deploying (publish) on pinux?

Comment: @jdweng I wan't to build on Linux. (CI/CD purposes)

Comment: Code on Windows. build on Linux. run on Linux.

Comment: The errors you get in windows will depend on the libraries you have installed and will not be the same as linux.  So are you getting the same errors in linux as you are in windows?  If you are getting different errors then you are not using the same libraries.  Don't forget the libraries are using libraries and all the libraries have to be the same.

Comment: @jdweng There are no errors on windows. and code runs just fine. the exact code is brought from windows to Linux. why should they have different libraries? the references are identical

Comment: The Net Library in many cases is just a wrapper that calls a windows dll.  So you will get errors if the windows dll is not present.  Just copying a project over from one machine to another the c# compiler will not automatically rebuild intermediate objects.  The  compiler only compiles object when the source is newer than object.  So if you are porting files between machines make sure you do a clean build so all the intermediate object get rebuilt.

Comment: Did you check in VS Solution Explorer that only references for linux are being used?

Comment: @jdweng I Cleaned and rebuilt the project on Linux. Errors didn't change..

Comment: @jdweng Yes you can see project `PackageReference` tags in my question. they're all the packages project depends on..

Comment: Do you have same latest version of libraries?  I suspect a library is wrong but not sure which one.  Had similar issue last week and OP found following :  "LibGpioD driver instead of SysFs interface in your Linux platform".    This issue was run time and not during compile.  So are the same compiler options being used on both machines.

Comment: @jdweng My error is in build, I think it means `compile` error. `runtime` errors will be my next problem :)

Comment: The error says exception"Unexpected exception: [/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/XXXXXX-pipeline/XXXXXX.DAL/XXXXXX.DAL.csproj]"  If it is a compiler error than an exception occurred during compile which means a library isn't compatible with your linux system.  See following : https://opensource.com/article/17/5/cross-platform-console-apps

Comment: @jdweng I will check. thank you

Comment: @user13747357 did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was mono package that needed to be installed. just install `mono-complete` package and the error might go away. I suggest following [this link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mono-on-debian-10/) for installation as it helped me.